# pre- calc continuous exponential decay model.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

i have looked at this problem for over an hour and can't figure out how to do it.

The mass of a radioactive substance follows a continuous exponential decay model, with a decay rate parameter of 9%
per day. A sample of this radioactive substance has an initial mass of 3kg
. Find the mass of the sample after three days. Round your answer to two decimal places.

Note: This is a continuous exponential decay model.
And though the decay rate parameter is 9%
per day, the actual decay is not 9%

each day.

Answer (score 2):

As the problem states, 9% the "decay rate parameter", not the daily decay rate. This problem is looking for use of the continuous decay formula, or $$P=P(0)e^{rt}$$In this particular problem, $$P=(3kg)e^{-.09*3}=2.29kg.$$

Comment: Right, that's the correct interpretation of "decay" rate (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A(k)$ is the amount of substance on day $k$. We know that we lose $9$% of the substance daily, and so we can claim the following:
$$A(k+1) = (1-.09)A(k) = 0.91\cdot A(k)$$
Using this relationship, we can see that
$$A(k+3) = 0.91\cdot A(k+2) = 0.91\cdot\left(0.91\cdot A(k+1)\right)= \dots = 0.91^3\cdot A(k)$$
If we know that $A(0) = 3$kg, what does $A(3)$ equal?

Comment: Then A(3)=2.26kg

Comment: Whether the decay ic continuous  or intermittent (like bank transactions) , if it's 9% per day  you will get the same result after exactly 3 days.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet:  but unlike bank transactions, radioactive decay is not capitalized once per day (o per hour) ! it is capitalized every $10^{-x}$ sec ! the OP's clarified that, and in that acception the right answer is that given by *zack*

Comment: as per the OP's note , and comment to Daniel Wainfleet, your answer is incorrect!